# filtering data frame based on NA on multiple columns

Tags: r, dataframe

I have the following data frame lets call it `df`, with the following observations:

```
id   type   company
1    NA      NA
2    NA      ADM
3    North   Alex
4    South   NA
NA   North   BDA
6    NA      CA
```

I want to retain only the records which do not have NA in column "type" and "company".

```
id   type   company
3    North   Alex
NA   North   BDA
```

I tried:

```
 df_non_na <- df[!is.na(df$company) || !is.na(df$type), ]
```

But this did not work.

Thanks in advance

Comment: `df [ complete.cases(df), ]` ?

Comment: Or the previous with a single `|` . ie:  `df[!is.na(df$company) | !is.na(df$type), ]`

Comment: I think this will remove the case where "id" is  NA

Comment: Could also try `library(data.table) ; na.omit(setDT(df), cols = c("type", "company"))`

Comment: @ David, thanks for this

Answer (score 19, accepted):

We can get the logical index for both columns, use `&` and subset the rows.

```
df1[!is.na(df1$type) & !is.na(df1$company),]
# id  type company
#3  3 North    Alex
#5 NA North     BDA
```

Or use `rowSums` on the logical matrix (`is.na(df1[-1])`) to subset.

```
df1[!rowSums(is.na(df1[-1])),]
```

Comment: Dena answered this, all I had to do was use "|" instead of "||",

Comment: But 1 `|` doesn't give you your desired output.

Comment: @user3875610  I get 6 rows from `df1[!is.na(df1$company) | !is.na(df1$type), ]`

Comment: @akrun Why can't we use `|` here? and Why `&` ? I thought `&` specifies only if both columns have `NA`.

Comment: @MAPK It iss a bit of reverse logic.  I guess it is the same logic from deMorgans law

Answer (score 40):

Using dplyr, you can also use the `filter_at` function

```
library(dplyr)
df_non_na <- df %>% filter_at(vars(type,company),all_vars(!is.na(.)))
```

`all_vars(!is.na(.))` means that all the variables listed need to be not NA.

If you want to keep rows that have at least one value, you could do:

```
df_non_na <- df %>% filter_at(vars(type,company),any_vars(!is.na(.)))
```

Comment: This answer is good for cases where you want to apply this filter to all except certain columns, too.  If you did `(vars(-type,-company)`, for example, you'd be exempting the type and company variables from having to not be na.

Answer (score 14):

You'll want to use `drop_na()`

```
library(dplyr)

new_df <- df %>% 
    drop_na(type, company)
```

Answer (score 10):

The example with `dplyr` (version >= 1.0.4) and `if_all()`, since `filter_at()` is superseded

```
id <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, NA, 6)
type <- c(NA, NA, "North", "South", "North", NA)
company <- c(NA, "ADM", "Alex", NA, "BDA", "CA")

df <- tibble(id, type, company)

library(dplyr)

df_non_na <- df %>% filter(if_all(c(type,company), ~ !is.na(.)))
```

Comment: `Using `across()` in `filter()` is deprecated, use `if_any()` or `if_all()`. `  but it works with one of those depending on what you're after.

Answer (score 7):

You need AND operator (&), not OR (|)
I also strongly suggest the tidyverse approach by using the dplyr function filter() and the pipe operator %>%, from dplyr as well:

```
library(dplyr)
df_not_na <- df %>% filter(!is.na(company) & !is.na(type))
```

Answer (score -5):

you can use

```
na.omit(data_frame_name)
```

Comment: That will eliminate rows that have *any* `NA` values -- accepted answer already does the job, question has been resolved.