# How to use dplyr across to filter NA in multiple columns

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to filter out rows with NA values across multiple columns. A row should only be dropped if all columns of interest are NA.

The scenario is the same as in this question (but I don't have enough reputation to make a comment): [filtering data frame based on NA on multiple columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33520854/filtering-data-frame-based-on-na-on-multiple-columns)

One of the solutions is to use:

```
library(dplyr)
df_non_na <- df %>% filter_at(vars(type,company),all_vars(!is.na(.)))
```

Since "filter_at" is being depreciated in dplyr, how can I use "filter" and "across" to achieve a similar outcome?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [dplyr filter with condition on multiple columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43938863/dplyr-filter-with-condition-on-multiple-columns)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

We can use `across` to loop over the columns 'type', 'company' and return the rows that doesn't have any NA in the specified columns

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
     filter(across(c(type, company), ~ !is.na(.)))
#     id  type company
#1  3 North    Alex
#2 NA North     BDA
```

---

With `filter`, there are two options that are similar to `all_vars/any_vars` used with `filter_at/filter_all`

```
df %>%
  filter(if_any(c(company, type), ~ !is.na(.)))
#  id  type company
#1  2  <NA>     ADM
#2  3 North    Alex
#3  4 South    <NA>
#4 NA North     BDA
#5  6  <NA>      CA
```

Or using `if_all`

```
    df %>%
      filter(!if_all(c(company, type), is.na))
   id  type company
1  2  <NA>     ADM
2  3 North    Alex
3  4 South    <NA>
4 NA North     BDA
5  6  <NA>      CA
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(id = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, NA, 6L), type = c(NA, NA, 
"North", "South", "North", NA), company = c(NA, "ADM", "Alex", 
NA, "BDA", "CA")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L
))
```

Comment: Is there a way to modify this so that only rows with multiple "NA" values are removed?

For example, so that only the first row in df (where both "type" and "company" are NA) would be removed.

Comment: @etrowbridge please check the updated solution

Comment: I tried to use `filter(if_all(c(variables), ~ !is.na(.)))` but it did not work as intended. I had to move the exclamation point before `if_all()`