# Exclude the columns whose column names contain a certain character, and drop the rows that contain NAs in the remaining columns

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, tidyverse

Suppose I have a dataframe `df` as below:

```
          date      CPI:YoY  PPI:MoM
1   2018-01-15           NA       NA
2   2018-01-31          1.2      0.2
3   2018-01-15           NA       NA
4   2018-02-28          0.9     -0.1
5   2018-03-15           NA       NA
6   2018-03-31          1.0      0.3
```

I need to implement the following two steps with `dplyr`: select the columns that do not contain `date`, and then drop the rows where all values in those columns are `NA`s.

To select columns not containing `date` can be implemented with the code: `dplyr::select(grep("date", names(df)))` or `dplyr::select(contains("date", ignore.case = TRUE))`; to drop NA rows in the selected columns we can use: `filter_at(vars(cols), all_vars(!is.na(.)))` or `dplyr::drop_na(cols)`.

Now my question is how to combine the two codes into one? Thanks.

***Note:*** For this example, we can simply use `drop_na(CPI:YoY, PPI:MoM)` to get the expected result, but since in real data, we usually have many columns, and the position of `date` column doesn't have to be the first column all the time, so I'd prefer to subset the columns by excluding the `date` column.

The expected result:

```
          date      CPI:YoY  PPI:MoM
1   2018-01-31          1.2      0.2
2   2018-02-28          0.9     -0.1
3   2018-03-31          1.0      0.3
```

**References:**

[Subset data to contain only columns whose names match a condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18587334/subset-data-to-contain-only-columns-whose-names-match-a-condition)

[filtering data frame based on NA on multiple columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33520854/filtering-data-frame-based-on-na-on-multiple-columns)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `filter` + `if_any/if_all`:

```r
df %>%
  filter( !if_all(-contains("date"), is.na) )
```

```r
df %>%
  filter( if_any(-contains("date"), ~ !is.na(.)) )
```

```r
df %>%
  filter( if_any(-contains("date"), Negate(is.na)) )
```

*Note: `Negate(is.na)` = `function(x) !is.na(x)` = `~ !is.na(.)`*

###### Output

```
        date CPI:YoY PPI:MoM
2 2018-01-31     1.2     0.2
4 2018-02-28     0.9    -0.1
6 2018-03-31     1.0     0.3
```

###### Data

```r
df <- read.table(text =
"         date      CPI:YoY  PPI:MoM
1   2018-01-15           NA       NA
2   2018-01-31          1.2      0.2
3   2018-01-15           NA       NA
4   2018-02-28          0.9     -0.1
5   2018-03-15           NA       NA
6   2018-03-31          1.0      0.3", check.names = FALSE)
```

Comment: Thank you for providing these alternative answers, very useful!